# Designing code work flow

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

Im making some code to interact with an API,
In order to use the API you need to get a session-key that you use for the rest of the requests, the session-key will become invalid after a while, so the code also needs to be prepared to reauth.

The code itself is not relevant nor the API since its a question about how to design the flow of the code, I'm looking for the best way to do it.

I don't have the code (javascript/node.js) here but here is basicly how it looks in pseudocode:

```
function getResult {
  data = foobar
  return getData(data, callback)
}

function getData(data, callback) {
  *building query (including the session-key) and getting data via http*
  if error == noauth
    auth()
    // What should happen here, I need to rerun the query
  else
   callback(result)
}

function auth {
  data = foobar
  getData(data, callback(?))
  // it returns a session-key to use 
  //What should happen here?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like:

```
function GetAuth(auth_params)
{
    // get session key
    return session key;
}

function MyAPIWorker(auth_params)
{
    this._auth_params = auth_params;
    this._current_auth = null;
}

MyAPIWorker.prototype.do(action)
{
    if (this._current_auth == null)
    {
    this._current_auth = GetAuth();
    }
    var result = action(this._current_auth);
    if (result == no_auth_error)
    {
    this._current_auth = GetAuth();
    result = action(this._current_auth);
    }
    return result;
}
```

then to use it you do:

```
worker = new MyAPIWorker(/* auth params here */);
worker.do(function (sessionKey) { /* do something with session key */});
/** blah blah **/
worker.do(function (sessionKey) { /* do other something with session key */});
```

The worker will handle all the heavy lifting for you...